# How to reverse each string in a string list at \n?

Tags: f#

I have this function which first reads the content of some files, then I have made the contents of the files into separate strings in a list. Then I want to access each element in the list and split the string when \n appears and reverse it. However I haven't been able to do the last part. How do I split each string in a string list when it comes across \n and then reverse the content?

An example. If I have a file that says "aaa\nbbb\n" and another that say "ccc\nddd\n" I want to split the string at \n at make the string says "ddd\nccc\nbbb\naaa\n "

Right now the output of the code underneath is Some "ccc\nddd\naaa\nbbb\n"

```
let tac (filenames:string list) : string option =
    let bal = List.map (fun x -> readFile(x)) filenames
    let mutable ral = []
    for elem in bal do
        let wal = [elem.Value]
        ral <- ral @ wal
    let sal = List.choose id ral |> List.rev |> String.concat """"""
    try
        Some(sal) 
    with
        | _ -> None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to run your code, I simplified it slightly, so I have just:

```
let bal = ["aa\nbb"; "cc\ndd"]
let mutable ral = []
for elem in bal do
    let wal = [elem]
    ral <- ral @ wal
let sal = bal |> List.rev |> String.concat ""
```

It seems that your code is also using `option` values in some way, but that's not relevant to this question. I also replace `""""""` with much simpler `""`. In your original code, you also have:

```
try Some(sal) with _ -> None
```

This is not necessary, because `Some(sal)` can never throw an exception. Now, in the code shown above, you have a `for` loop and then you use `List.rev`. The `for` loop is just recreating the same list, so this is not making much sense. You could either change the loop to reverse the list and drop `List.rev` or you could drop `List.rev`. I'll do the former:

```
let bal = ["aa\nbb"; "cc\ndd"]
let sal = bal |> List.rev |> String.concat ""
```

This takes a list of strings, reverses it and then concatenates the strings in reversed order. You also want to reverse each string. To do this, you can take characters of the string, reverse them and then turn them into strings and concatenate those:

```
"abc" |> Seq.rev |> Seq.map string |> String.concat ""
```

To do this for all strings in your original list, you can use `List.map`:

```
let sal = 
  bal 
  |> List.map (fun s -> 
      s |> Seq.rev |> Seq.map string |> String.concat "") 
  |> List.rev |> String.concat ""
```